# How to add threads to an ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have a class, SmartQueue which extends Thread and looks like this

```
public class SmartQueue extends Thread {
    public int idQ;
    public LinkedList<Client> sQueue = new LinkedList<Client>();
    ......
//pops an element from sQueue after a random time in a specified interval
//and then waits to be notified again
```

From another class, QManager I want to create a few threads of SmartQueue inside a for loop and keep track of them by adding them to an ArrayList. Then add one element at a time in SmartQueue.sQueue at some random time in another specified interval. Also the removal of an element in SmartQueue would also be triggered in class QManager by..."extracting" the thread from the ArrayList and notifying it.

Basically I am trying to create a queue simulator where generated "clients" arrive and are served at/in some random time, with each queue having it's own processor and running as a thread at the same time with the other queues

Is the ArrayList way of keeping track of the threads viable or it's...just stupid?
How should I do it? Also any ideas on how to implement this simulator are welcomed

Comment: Is a SmartQueue a Thread? Is there really reason to extend Thread?

Comment: Yes SmartQueue is a thread. Each instance of SmartQueue is a thread, and all the instances should run concurrently

Comment: What @svenoaks may be trying to say is, extending Thread is a 20th century way of defining your thread's entry point.  The 21st century way is to instantiate the naked Thread class, and give it a Runnable delegate.  `new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { ... }});`  The long-term benefit is that it gets you in the habit of using delegation instead of using type inheritance---one step along the path to writing clean, re-useable, maintainable code.

Comment: yeah, I know that using Runnable is better but...truth be told I haven't worked to much with threads and I find it a bit harder to use Runnable, but I got comfortable quite fast with using Thread, I mean it's basically just inheritance. I agree, there's the long-term benefit but I don't have to much time and I need to get this done fast, it's an assessment at the university. It's easier this way. The code won't be reused or mantained afterwards in any major way. More likely it will be forgotten. Afterwards I will try some personal projects and I will start using Runnable there. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue pointed out in the comments is more than just a cosmetic thing. Making subclasses of `Thread` leads to wrong thinking which is perfectly shown by your question.

Threads accessing a variable do not have any relationship with the object holding the variable, even if the object happens to be an instance of `Thread`. Creating a subclass of `Thread` and putting instance variables into it leads to the wrong thinking that there was a relationship between the thread represented by the `Thread` instance and the variables of that instance.

It’s symptomatic that you are asking whether you can place these instances into an `ArrayList` which, of course, you can do as the fact that they are instances of `Thread` has no relevance here.

But given your incomplete description of what you want to do it seems that you will have at least one thread accessing the `LinkedList<Client>` held in `sQueue` via `QManager` while another thread (which happens to be the one represented by your `SmartQueue` instance but that remains irrelevant) will do as well. That will break unless you take actions for implementing thread safe access to the `LinkedList`. So you have focused on the wrong place regarding thread safety just because your `SmartQueue` extends `Thread`…

Comment: Ok, but...will using Runnable allow me to see each thread as a separate instance of SmartQueue with it's own variables? If not, how could I do that? Could I in the first place?

Comment: threads are *no* instances of SmartQueue. Never. That’s the whole point, making `SmartQueue` a subclass of `Thread` makes you think there was a relationship that simply doesn’t exist. Using `Runnable` helps you to understand that threads are only executing an *action*, i.e. the code inside the `run` method, nothing more. Whether the contained variables are accessed by one or more threads depends on your entire application logic. And as said, your (vague) description indicates that you *want* access the data by multiple threads. So you must make them thread safe.

Comment: yes, ok, i get the point, threads are not objects basically they just..."do something". What I was thinking to do was to...bind each thread to a certain instance of the same class so each thread could _act_ and modify a variable(`sQueue` in this case) of a certain instance of a class (`SmartQueue`). It would be very easy to do it sequentially in a loop but I'm trying to do this concurrently, at the same time(...at least from the software point of view), and I kind of got confused and I don't really know how to do it

Comment: It is no problem to assign each thread an object it should work on. You only have to pass it to the `Runnable` or you could even let `SmartQueue` implement `Runnable` so its `run` method would work on the right object, naturally. However, having assigned the object to the worker thread does not automatically prevent other threads from accessing the same object. You have to design the application appropriately. And as far as I understand, you want the threads to take and process items from the their queue but there is someone else putting the items. So you need to use a thread-safe queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. Any Queue, LinkedList or ArrayList would work OK, provided the QueueManager is single threaded.